# How does Angular2 handle Location response header

Tags: angular, http-headers

When on a typical webpage, in response to an http request I do:

```
<?php
header('Location: http://example.com');
exit;
```

The browser automatically follows the location header to the new site.

However, if the front-end is an Angular2 application, the browser doesn't follow this instruction.  Is this by design? Has any of you come across documentation on how Angular2 handles the `Location` response header?